# Material-UI - fetching data display in DataTable => "React.useState" cannot be called inside a callback

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

I made a copy of ReactTables.js and I've been modifying it to display my own data.  At first, I put my data in the /variables/general.js file, and I'm able to display it in the table.

The next step is to fetch the data from a REST service.
I've written functions to do that, and tested them in Node first, even the fetch part, and now I'm trying to fold them in the React code. I know the data is formatted correctly for the dataTable structure.

When I switch from static data, to fetch data and put "React.useState" under the .then clause, I start getting error: React Hook "React.useState" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks.
I tried putting my code under the React.use but looks like it is wanting parms, not code there.

This is the code I have, excluding the actions and the styles. Again, it's basically their out-of-the-box code, just trying to insert the fetch to get dynamic data. I need to use a .then when I call my getDBLanguagesAndConvertToDataTable.

I did some basic reading about hooks, but got lost. Is there another place I should be retrieving the data from the REST service?

```
import React from "react";

// @material-ui/core components
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
// @material-ui/icons
import Assignment from "@material-ui/icons/Assignment";
import Dvr from "@material-ui/icons/Dvr";
import Favorite from "@material-ui/icons/Favorite";
import Close from "@material-ui/icons/Close";
// core components
import GridContainer from "components/Grid/GridContainer.js";
import GridItem from "components/Grid/GridItem.js";
import Button from "components/CustomButtons/Button.js";
import Card from "components/Card/Card.js";
import CardBody from "components/Card/CardBody.js";
import CardIcon from "components/Card/CardIcon.js";
import CardHeader from "components/Card/CardHeader.js";
import ReactTable from "components/ReactTable/ReactTable.js";

import { dataTable } from "variables/general.js";

import { cardTitle } from "assets/jss/material-dashboard-pro-react.js";

const styles = {
  cardIconTitle: {
    ...cardTitle,
    marginTop: "15px",
    marginBottom: "0px"
  }
};

const useStyles = makeStyles(styles);

function convertMongoLanguagesToDataTable(argDbGetResults) {
  //console.log("function convertMongoLanguagesToDataTable")
  //console.log("Input:" + JSON.stringify(argDbGetResults))
  const dataTable = {
      headerRow: ["SourceLanguage", "SourcePhrase", "TargetLanguage", "TargetPhrase", "ID"],
      footerRow: ["SourceLanguage", "SourcePhrase", "TargetLanguage", "TargetPhrase", "ID"],
      dataRows: []
      };
  var temporaryMax = argDbGetResults.length
  temporaryMax = 3  // get a smaller sample for easier debugging/testing 
  for (var j = 0; j < argDbGetResults.length; j++) {
    var row = argDbGetResults[j]
    var strRow = JSON.stringify(row);   
    //console.log(j, strRow)
    var newArray = [row.masterLanguage, row.masterPhrase, row.localizedLanguage, row.localizedPhrase, row._id]
    dataTable.dataRows.push(newArray)
  }
  //console.log("return from function convertMongoLanguagesToDataTable")
  //console.log("dataTable:" + JSON.stringify(dataTable))
  return dataTable 
}

function getDBLanguagesAndConvertToDataTable(fromLanguage, toLanguage) { 
  // pass the from/to Language on the URL 
  var url = 'http://localhost:3001/api/gettranslations/' + fromLanguage + "/" + toLanguage 
  var fetchOptions = {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json',
          }
    }
  return fetch(url, fetchOptions)
    .then(function(data) {
      // do something with the data 
      data.json()
        .then (function(fetchResult) {
            //console.log("data.json() from Fetch From gettranslation REST service:")
            //console.log(JSON.stringify(fetchResult)) 
        
            var tmpDataTable = convertMongoLanguagesToDataTable(fetchResult)
            console.log("return from function convertMongoLanguagesToDataTable")
            console.log("PostFetch dataTable:" + JSON.stringify(tmpDataTable))

            return tmpDataTable
        }) 
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        console.log("Fetch Error url:" + url)
        console.log("Fetch Error:" + err)
        throw new Error(err) 
    })
}

export default function ReactTables() {
  
  
  var fromLanguage = 'en-US'
  var toLanguage = 'es-MX'
  getDBLanguagesAndConvertToDataTable(fromLanguage, toLanguage) 
  .then(function(dataTable) {
  console.log("tmpDataTable type=" + typeof dataTable)
  var strDataTable = JSON.stringify(dataTable, null, 3);    
  console.log("Resulting DataTable=")
  console.log(strDataTable)     
   

  if (dataTable === null || dataTable === undefined) {
    console.log('dataTable is null or undefined')
  }
  if (dataTable.dataRows === null || dataTable.dataRows === undefined) {
    console.log('dataTable.dataRows is null or undefined')
  }
  console.log("Number of dataRows=" + dataTable.dataRows.length)

  
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(

    dataTable.dataRows.map((prop, key) => {
      return {
        ID: key,
        SourceLanguage: prop[0],
        SourcePhrase: prop[1],
        TargetLanguage: prop[2],
        TargetPhrase: prop[3],
        actions: (
           // code omitted 
        )
      };
    })
  );
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
     // code omitted 
  );
  })  // end of .then for getting dataTable 
}
```

EDIT - Part 2

New code after trying Marcos answer.  I had to comment out the final ")" at the end of the map. It compiles, but now gives error:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {ID, SourceLanguage, SourcePhrase, TargetLanguage, TargetPhrase, actions}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in ReactTables (created by Context.Consumer)
```

Code

```
export default function ReactTables() {
  
  const [data, setData] = React.useState()
      
React.useEffect(() => {
  var fromLanguage = 'en-US'
  var toLanguage = 'es-MX'
  getDBLanguagesAndConvertToDataTable(fromLanguage, toLanguage) 
  .then(function(dataTable) {
        console.log("tmpDataTable type=" + typeof dataTable)
        var strDataTable = JSON.stringify(dataTable, null, 3) 
        console.log("dataTable=")
        console.log(dataTable)     
      
        if (dataTable === null || dataTable === undefined) {
          console.log('dataTable is null or undefined')
        }
        if (dataTable.dataRows === null || dataTable.dataRows === undefined) {
          console.log('dataTable.dataRows is null or undefined')
        }
        console.log("Number of dataRows=" + dataTable.dataRows.length)

        setData(dataTable)
    });
}, [])



    return dataTable.dataRows.map((prop, key) => {
      return {
        ID: key,
        SourceLanguage: prop[0],
        SourcePhrase: prop[1],
        TargetLanguage: prop[2],
        TargetPhrase: prop[3],
        actions: (
           // code omitted 
        )
      };
    })
  //);   -- had to comment this out! 
  
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <GridContainer>
       // Code omitted 
    </GridContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hooks can only be called on the rendering function, have to always be called if used, and always in the same order.

You're using `useState` in the callback of a `Promise`. Instead of that you have to use it on the component and use `useEffect` to call your data fetching logic and set the state based on the result.

If you need to manipulate the data in order to show it you can use `useMemo` to get the processed data from the original one and do this only when the data changes. Be sure to get the data from `data` set in the state.

Finally, because `useEffect` will run after the initial render your data wont necessarily be available either because the data is being retrieved or there was an error. You can handle this with a conditional return, just make sure you place all hooks before the conditional return because as stated before, you cannot modify any calls to any hooks in-between renders.

```js
export default function ReactTables() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState()

  React.useEffect(() => {
    getDBLanguagesAndConvertToDataTable()
      .then(result => {
        setData(result)
      });
  }, [])

  const processedData = React.useMemo(() => data && data.dataRows.map((prop, key) => {
    return {
      ID: key,
      SourceLanguage: prop[0],
      SourcePhrase: prop[1],
      TargetLanguage: prop[2],
      TargetPhrase: prop[3],
      actions: (
         // code omitted 
      )
    };
  }), [data])
 
  const classes = useStyles()

  if (!processedData) {
    return null // Use a loading component if you prefer
  }

  return (
    <GridContainer>
       // Code omitted 
    </GridContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks easy, but I tried it and might have misinterpreted something.  I put my code in "Part 2" of my question and the new error I got (Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys).  Could you take a look at it?

Comment: Also if I comment out this line "//import { dataTable } from "variables/general.js";", then I get "Line 138:12:  'dataTable' is not defined  no-undef" where that is the "return datatTable.dataRows.map" line.

Comment: @NealWalters i've updated the code to give you better guidance in how to achieve this and make use of some useful hooks. Take your time to get it working and try reading about hooks if you feel you're missing some theory.

Comment: I know I have a lot of reading and studying to do, but was trying to get out a quick Proof of Concept.  Now the events seem to be firing in some crazy order.  I have a lot of console.logs and I see in this order.  class=useStyles - processedData is still not loaded 
About to call getDBLanguages...
dataTable type=undefined [I thought I had this working before] 
Back from function convertMongoLanguagesToDataTable
  (correct data for dataTable).   The page is blank because of the processData returning null. Is that the right order, some way to retrigger the useStyles after data load?

Comment: try debugging to know why `processedData` is null and see why your data processing logic is not returning valid data even after its retrieval, it is right for it to be null when the data is not fetched yet though. `useStyles` is and independent hook and should work even if you return `null`, which I think is the root issue you're having right now

Comment: I thought my fetch was tested, but found a missing "return"; needed in front of the data.json. Example      return data.json()     .then (function(fetchResult) {"... 
Now I'm on to the next error:  TypeError: data.forEach is not a function
accessRowsForColumn

Comment: I used CircularJSON.stringify to look at the value of processedData.  It's over 48 MB in size, console.log cuts it off; does that sound right?  I even changed to "actions: (<div>Test</div>)" and it's still huge.  http://mylifeismymessage.net/temp/processedData.txt.  But the variable called data looks good. Also removed actions (based on what Giovanni said)

Answer (score 2):

Ciao, `React.useState` is used to define a state variable and must be used in component body. Something like:

```
export default function ReactTables(){
   const [data, setData] = React.useState([]) // [] this is the initial value for data
   ...
}
```

Then, on `.then` callback you could set this state by calling `setData(/*data from fetch*/)`.

**PART 2**

Supposing that `dataTable.dataRows` is an array, I think your problem is in `map` function, in particular in `actions`. You cannot return something like `actions: (...)` because circular brackets are not allowed in JSON object. If `actions` is an array, replace `actions: (...)` with `actions: [...]`. If `actions` is an object, replace `actions: (...)` with `actions: {...}`

Comment: I can't quite follow your example,  I did make changes based on Marco's example below, and still had some issue.  Could you also look at "Part 2" in my original question.  Thanks.

Comment: @NealWalters I updated my answer with the second part. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Now using Marco's template I'm getting "TypeError: data.forEach is not a function".  I have remove actions for now.  Seem like data is getting built correctly, but now not matching what React wants.  I have reached out to the seller to ask for help.  When I had actions, processed data was huge, like 48 MB (and console.log truncates it).